# What is the fastest way to search through strings in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am implementing a sort of autocomplete for an iOS app. The data I am using for the autocomplete values is a comma-separated text file with about 100,000 strings. This is what I am doing now:

1. Read the text file, and create an `NSArray` with 100,000 `NSString`.
2. As the user types, do `[array containsObject:text]`

Surely there is a better/faster way to do this lookup. Any thoughts?

Comment: You could try to skip through strings that dont even match the first letter, no point in searching from apples to yogurt if your word is zebra. I'm not sure of the best way to implement this, perhaps a multidimensional array? First dimension could be first letter, second dimension second letter, etc, until like 3rd or 4th letter, then you could just contain the remainder of the word.

Comment: If you don't need ordering I think that sets are faster when checking if it contains an object or not. It's still not optimized for strings though. You should probably look into things like binary trees etc. if you need to make custom code the general approach would be similar no matter the platform/language you are working with.

Comment: There's *always* a faster way. Are you seeing lag in your UI, though? I've done the exact same thing for autocomplete (with a smaller input array) and had no visible lag, despite the naive search algorithm.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Absolutely, there is! It's not "in Objective-C" though: most likely, you would need to code it yourself.

The idea is to convert your list of string to a [*suffix tree*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree), a data structure that lets you search by prefix very quickly. Searching for possible completions in a suffix tree are very fast, but the structure itself is not easy to build. A quick search on the internet revealed that there is no readily available implementation in Objective C, but you may be able to [port an implementation](http://illya-keeplearning.blogspot.com/2009/04/suffix-trees-java-ukkonens-algorithm.html) [in another language](http://code.google.com/p/simplesuffixtree/), [use a C implementation](http://mila.cs.technion.ac.il/~yona/suffix_tree/), or even write your own if you are not particularly pressed for time.

Perhaps an easier approach would be to sort your strings alphabetically, and run a binary search on the prefix that has been entered so far. Though not as efficient as a suffix tree, the sorted array approach will be acceptable for 100K strings, because you get to the right spot in under seventeen checks.

Comment: +1 for pointing out Objective-C is C and you shouldn't be afraid to drop down to C when looking at performance intensive tasks :) I'll also second the binary tree which is probably the easiest to implement.

Comment: NDTrie (https://github.com/nathanday/ndtrie) and PJTernarySearchTree (https://github.com/peakji/PJTernarySearchTree) are precisely this in Objective-C!

Comment: After some tests, PJTernarySearchTree was faster and more memory efficient than NDTrie, but this may just be anecdotal evidence based on circumstantial dataset characteristics. :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest is probably binary search. See `-[NSArray indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:]`.

In particular, I'd try something like this:

- Pre-sort the array that you save to the file
- When you load the array, possibly `@selector(compare:)` (if you are worried about it being accidentally unsorted or the Unicode sort order changing for some edge cases). This should be approximately O(n) assuming the array is mostly sorted already.
- To find the first potential match, `[array indexOfObject:searchString inSortedRange:(NSRange){0,[array count]} options:NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex|NSBinarySearchingFirstEqual usingComparator:@selector(compare:)]`
- Walk down the array until the entries no longer contain searchString as a prefix. You probably want to do case/diacritic/width-insensitive comparisons to determine whether it is a prefix (NSAnchoredSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch|NSWidthInsensitiveSearch)

This may not "correctly" handle all locales (Turkish in particular), but neither will replacing `compare:` with `localizedCompare:`, nor will naïve string-folding. (It is only 9 lines long, but took about a day of work time to get right and has about 40 lines of code and 200 lines of test, so I probably shouldn't share it here.)